# Index2word in Gensim's Doc2vec raises an Attribute error

Tags: python, gensim

I trained a doc2vec (gensim.models.Doc2Vec) model and now I'm using this line:

```
print(dict([(model.index2word[i], similarity) for i, similarity in enumerate(model.similar_by_word('igdumd32.dll@0x', topn=False))])['igdumd64.dll@0x'])
```

but it yields this error:
AttributeError: 'Doc2Vec' object has no attribute 'index2word'

I am using gensim 1.0.1

Can you help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `index2word` list of word-vectors has moved to the `wv` property of the model in recent gensim versions, so where you would say `model.index2word` you must now use `model.wv.index2word`.

(Note that this is still just word-vectors, which are only trained by the "DM" `dm=1` Doc2Vec modes. Doc-vectors are in the `model.docvecs` object, and you can see a list of the string tags to which doc-vectors may be associated in `model.docvecs.offset2doctag`.)